# Iframe scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using an iframe to pull in a widget developed on a different domain.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://otherdomain.com" width="100%" data-embed="true" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
```

Within that iframe I have a series of screens that a user navigates through. These are basic show()/hide():

```
<section id="step1">
    CONTENT FOR SCREEN ONE<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT<br>LOTS OF CONTENT
</section>    
<section id="step2" style="display:none;">
    CONTENT FOR SCREEN 2
</section>    
<section id="step3" style="display:none;">
    CONTENT FOR SCREEN 3
</section>    
<section id="step4" style="display:none;">
    CONTENT FOR SCREEN 4
</section>
```

The problem is on mobile (Android/FF and iphone/Safari) when you navigate from screen 1, where there is lots of content and link at bottom, to screen 2, the screen is still scrolled to the bottom of screen 2!

I have added the following jQUery:

```
$('#top').focus();
```

And an input box at the top of the iframe content:

```
<input type="text" id="top" style="" />
```

This works! And it brings the user to the top of the iframe content. I tried to change the input box to a div but it doesnt work. I then tried to hide the input box but it still brings up the mobile "keyboard" as you focus in the input box.

How can I successfully jump to the top of the page without using an input box?